Was Charles always aware of Zero's identity?
During another one of my countless rewatches, I noticed that in episode 5, at the end, someone approaches Charles and tells him that Clovis's remains have arrived. Charles responds that he had just finished talking to Clovis and that they need to hurry with the execution of the plan.
I don't fully remember the extent of Charles's Geass ability or what the Sword of Akasha is capable of at that point (feel free to elaborate if it answers the question), but if he had truly spoken to Clovis, to whom Lelouch did reveal his identity, shouldn't Charles realize that Lelouch is Zero from the very beginning of the series?
